# Pasting data to new worksheet where A-E are non-empty

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble getting a copied row to paste into a different worksheet, on the first available row.

Problem is I need the data to paste into column B but my macro pastes into other columns. Column A has a Vlookup formula and columns B-E have specific drop-downs which excel sees as non-empty cells.

I don't know if this is causing the problem?

My code;

```
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Dispute_Details")
ws.Activate
On Error Resume Next
iRow = Range("F:F").Find(What:=" ", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
Sheets(ws).Range("b", iRow).Activate

Worksheets("Dispute_Details").Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim iRow As Long
With Worksheets("Dispute_Details")
    iRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Range("B" & iRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
```